# Why chromium is installed on my Mac, after I installed Android studio?

Tags: macos, install, android

I have chromium installed on my Mac, but I did not install not.
it's not on my applications folder.. Also, when I try to see where it's stored? I found it inside Android studio SDK.. there's more than one file of (README.Chromium).
The question is.. is it a virus ? or it's just normal to have it installed with Android studio?
because I can't get it, if it's an SDK that comes with Android studio, then why it appear as application? on notification and open with menu..
I also find it in Activity monitor..

[image: screenbshot 3]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshoot 1]

Comment: I also have Android Studio (public release and canary) installed on Mac, but there's no Chromium installed.

Comment: @AndrewT. I'm afraid it's a virus then! I I will delete Android studio

Comment: @AndrewT. when I run emulator pixel 3! chromium shows in activity monitor..I guess it's installed through emulator :)